# How to calculate average using inactive relationship and SUMMARIZE function in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have inactive relationship from `dim_Date[Date]` to `fact_Loss[DateClosed]` .

I need to calculate an average monthly number of Closed Claims by `DateClosed`.

I was able to calculate monthly ClosedClaims by using `USERELATIONSHIP`:

**1) Calculated TotalClosedClaims**

```
Ttl Closed Claims =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( fact_Loss[ClaimID] ),
    FILTER ( fact_Loss, fact_Loss[ClaimStatus] = "Closed" )
)
```

**2) calculated Closed claims per Month date closed**

```
Claims by Closed Date =
CALCULATE (
    [Ttl Closed Claims],
    USERELATIONSHIP ( fact_Loss[DateClosed], dim_Date[Date] )
)
```

[image]

**Result looks correct:**

[image]

But now I simply need to take Average on those monhts: 
I am trying somehting like this:

```
AVG Closed Claims = 
CALCULATETABLE(
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( fact_Loss, fact_Loss[ClosedMMYY] <> BLANK () ),
        fact_Loss[ClosedMMYY],
        "Average", COUNT ( fact_Loss[ClaimID] )
    ),USERELATIONSHIP(fact_Loss[DateClosed],dim_Date[Date])
)
```

But it doesn't give me correct number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like =[AVERAGEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/averagex-function-dax)(VALUES(dim_Date[MM-YY]), [Claims by Closed Date]) should work. Hard to tell without the data or pbix.

Comment: Oh! That was simple. What "Value" function do in this case? Thanks

Comment: Yay! Glad to hear it. Values ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/values-function-dax ) returns a distinct column of selected or crossfiltered values from the specified column.